# a selector which has this selector together with a class selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Here is an analogy of my problem(a selector which has this selector together with a class selector):

Let say that I selects all yellow(classes) div elements in a arbitrary HTML document. And I want each to check if the attribute is yes = 1. If the attribute 'yes' equals '1', then I want the child with class 'blue' have the attribute 'no' equals '1';

```
$('div .yellow').each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('yes') == 1){
      $(this '.blue:first-child').attr('no', 1);//This line needs to be fixed 
   }
});
```

I know that the line `this.getElementsByClassName('blue')[0]` fixes this problem. But in my real problem (not this analogy) I want to use addClass and removeClass which only functions with jQuery objects. It is to cumbersome to use other functions than addClass and removeClass.

UPDATE:

Here is a code snippet from my real problem. I got some problem with "this" in javascript.

I want a invited button to have the className visible when I click on it. The button lies within a div element with className 'box'. I know that there are problem with 'this' on the code snippet. But I want the button and not the box to change to visible

```
$('.Box').each(function(){
        if($(this).attr('hasButton') != 1){

            var invite = document.createElement('div');
            invite.className = 'invite invisible';
            invite.innerHTML = 'invite';
            $(this).attr('hasButton', 1);
            this.appendChild(invite);
            invite.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event){
                $('.invite', this).removeClass('invisible');//this line is not functioning
                $('.invite', this).addClass('visible');//neither this
            }, false);
        }
    });
```

Ok solved it. I passed an element as attribute instead of classSelector.

```
$(invite).removeClass('invisible');
 $(invite).addClass('visible');
```

Comment: By the way, if you want to select yellow `div` elements you should drop that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean each blue `div` lives in its own yellow `div`? If so, try this:

```
$('.blue:first-child', this).attr('no', 1);
```

This tells jQuery to select `.blue` elements only found within the scope of `this` (which refers to the `.yellow` element currently being iterated by `each()`).

Comment: Yes the div lives in the yellow div. But I didn't got it to function in my real problem. I post a code snippet soon.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div .yellow[yes=1] .blue:first-child').attr('no', 1);
```

You can use the `tagname[attrname=attrvalue]` to match arbitrary attributes.

You can also use `find()` to only look within a specific element.

```
var yellow = $('div .yellow[yes=1]');
yellow.find('.blue:first-child').attr('no', 1);
```